# Wordpress hook fires before, not after the call

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

What I'm triyng to achieve is working with the WP REST API and hooking the user meta data update.
Here's the link to the action reference:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/updated_%28meta_type%29_meta

where it says:

"This hook is called **after** a call to update_metadata succeeds. "

This is the code:

```
add_action( 'updated_user_meta', 'second_otp', 10, 4 );

function second_otp($meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $_meta_value) {
            $otp = $_meta_value;
            $message = "Your OTP =" . get_user_meta($object_id, "otp", true ) . get_user_meta($object_id, "nickname", true );
            $to = 'myemail@msn.com';
            $subject = 'OTP';
            $body = $message;
            $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
            wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );  
};
```

But the action "updated_user_meta" is triggered BEFORE the meta field is written. E.g. if the user has the OTP="1111", and I send this json

```
{
    "id": "31",
  "roles": "verified",
  "meta": {"otp":"2222"}
}
```

to the `http://MYSITE/dev/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/users/31/` endpoint
I will get an email with the body:

```
"Your OTP = 1111"
```

Is there anything I haven't counted, that would help me to email the new OTP of the user, that I'm sending via REST api, and not the old one?

Comment: After you make the REST API call, is the otp meta value in fact set to "2222" ?

Comment: Yes, @incredimike

Comment: In the [source code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.8/src/wp-includes/meta.php#L0), the line `do_action( "updated_{$meta_type}_meta", $meta_id, $object_id, $meta_key, $_meta_value );` is fired for every single meta value. So you would have to check in your callback function whether the `$meta_key` parameter actually equals `otp` and only then send your email with the updated value.

Comment: @Michael, yes mate, I'm aware, thanx. This code was simplified here for testing purpose.

Comment: Well, doesn't really matter if it's updated before or after, as long as the `$_meta_value` passed to your function is the updated one. If you do the check I mentioned, you could assemble your `$message` using the `$_meta_value` directly, instead of getting it via `get_user_meta()`. Why getting it if you already have it?

Comment: I bet checking the $meta_key is what's missing. For poops and giggles, try adding `if ($meta_key == 'otp') return;` to the top of the function to skip all other meta updates. you are probably getting the email too early, before the otp meta is actually updated.

Comment: @incredimike thanx